# Relative homology groups for torus with a point removed

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I am trying to compute the relative homology $H_{n}(X, \partial X)$ for all $n \geq 0$, where $X$ is a torus with a point removed.

$X$ is homotopy equivalent to wedge sum of two circles $S^{1} \vee S^{1}$, this is easy.

I know how the long exact sequence for relative homology looks like, but i am not sure how $\partial X$ looks like. Can anybody help me with this question, please?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by $\partial X$?  The boundary of $X$ as a manifold?  In that case, $\partial X$ is empty...

Comment: Yes, i mean the boundary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $X$ is an open subset of the torus, every point of $X$ has a neighborhood homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$.  That is, $X$ is a manifold without boundary, so $\partial X=\emptyset$.  So $H_*(X,\partial X)=H_*(X,\emptyset)$ is just the same as $H_*(X)$.

Comment: Then everything is fine! Thank you very much!